# DisplayPort Audio-In via Microphone

Tags: microphone, displayport

I connected my new [monitor](http://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-27UD88-W-4k-uhd-led-monitor) via DisplayPort. The monitor features a 3.5 mm jack and I plugged in my headset. Audio-Output works fine, but I cannot use the microphone and don't see a addiditional microphone in the sound panel.

I'm using ThinkPad X220 and GNOME 3.26, with Archlinux. So I assume the drivers support everything which is possible. I didn't found a note about audio-input and DisplayPort on the web. Did I searched wrong or does DisplayPort (and HDMI probably too?) doesn't features Audio-Input i.e. a microphone?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't the 3.5mm jack audio-out only? Check your user's manual. And typically DP and HDMI are not two-way audio.

Comment: The manual states only H/P-Out (HeadPhones-Out).

Comment: There's your answer.

Comment: Thanks. They should make me the head of VESA, I will fix that ;)